# Visual C# 2017 Code Editor suddenly stopped copying as rich text

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-editor

I usually copy codes from Visual C# 2017 and paste it in MS Word as colored code. But today it suddenly stopped copying colored code and when I copy the code it is copied just as plain text. I did not find any options in settings to fix this. What is a happened and how can I copy the code as rich text again?

I have restarted Visual C# and The computer and it is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your options in word. File->Options->Advance->cutting copying pasting section and change option in dropdown on keep source formatting (or something similar I don't know how it is name in your word language version).